# How to secure an Internet-facing Elastic Search implementation in a shared hosting environment?

Tags: security, elasticsearch

I've been going over the documentation for [Elastic Search](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) and I'm a *big* fan and I'd like to use it to handle the search for my ASP.NET MVC app.

That introduces a few interesting twists, however.  If the ASP.NET MVC application was on a dedicated machine, it would be simple to spool up an instance of Elastic Search and use the [TCP Transport](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/modules/transport.html) to connect locally.

However, I'm not on a dedicated machine for the ASP.NET MVC application, nor does it look like I'll move to one anytime soon.

That leaves hosting Elastic Search on another machine (in the *NIX world) and I would probably go with shared hosting there.

One of the biggest things lacking from Elastic Search, however, is the fact that it doesn't support HTTPS and basic authentication out of the box.  If it did, then this question wouldn't exist; I'd simply host it somewhere and make sure to have an incredibly secure password and HTTPS enabled (possibly with a self-signed certificate).

But that's not the case.

That given, what is a good way to expose Elastic Search over the Internet in a secure way?

Note, I'm looking for something that hopefully, will not require writing code to provide shims for the methods that I want (in other words, writing forwarders).

Comment: Now there is [a plugin](https://github.com/Asquera/elasticsearch-http-basic) to support basic auth

Comment: Basic auth sends passwords as plain text, with every request. It's considered completely obsolete.

Comment: yes. I didn't said it is a complete solution ... you'll need to add https

Comment: I am the author of the plugin. Basically, its a short experiment to see how well you can replace the HttpServer class in ElasticSearch. First of all, you should really use this with HTTPS by deploying some kind of SSL offloader in front of it (e.g. Nginx). Secondly: It doesn't do "full" HTTP basic, because you cannot add arbitrary headers to a HTTP response in Elasticsearch. This also bars implementation of Digest Auth. Digest Auth also has a major drawback: It requires a round-trip for every new connection, which is nor acceptable in my use-case.

Comment: NB: This question eventually migrated to ServerFault: http://serverfault.com/questions/240707/how-to-secure-an-internet-facing-elastic-search-implementation-in-a-shared-hosti

Comment: Have a look at elasticsearch's offering [shield](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/shield/current/getting-started.html).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A [plugin for elasticsearch that allows you to replace the HTTP transport with an embedded instance of Jetty](https://github.com/sonian/elasticsearch-jetty) is now available.

Because it uses Jetty to handle the HTTP transport, it can handle SSL connections as well as be configured for authentication.

---

(Note, the following is still sound advice, in that it's generally good practice to abstract your operations out in this manner)

After a number of discussions on the [ElasticSearch mailing list](http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/), I've discovered that the current solution is to host ElasticSearch behind another application layer and then to secure *that* layer.

The reasoning is solid; ElasticSearch is akin to a database, and you wouldn't make your database public-facing to all.

Something that I (and others) trip up on is that because ElasticSearch uses HTTP as a transport and uses JSON as the syntax for operations, that ElasticSearch is meant to be public-facing.

However, there is currently a [request](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/664) to add HTTPS transport support (assuming a certificate is provided) along with basic (digest) authentication.

Comment: When securing the layer in front of Elasticsearch, there's a few things to keep in mind as well. This article on [Securing Your Elasticsearch Cluster](https://www.found.no/foundation/elasticsearch-security/) has some coverage.

Comment: Comes up with a question, answers it then closes it as off topic.
Boss B|

Answer (score 6):

You'll have to firewall the machine in some way, permitting only the traffic from the appserver, e.g. using iptables on linux, or some kind of personal firewall on windows.

This takes you into serverfault.com territory, though - there isn't a programming solution to this one.

Comment: Given that will be in a shared environment, I won't have control over that, most likely.  Or will I?

Comment: @casperOne: Out of my league, that is. I use Elastic Search (and yes, I love it too) in a 3rd-party linux virtual hosting environment, and use the host's own iptables to firewall it. It's virtualized, so I can do what I like with it.

Comment: Can you comment on what the costs are like for that, as well as what might be required to get that up and running?  Of course, just firewalling it based on IP isn't *completely* secure in my case, as other apps on the same shared instance would be able to access my Elastic Search instance.

Comment: @casparOne: $50 per month, or something along those lines. I delegate that sort of stuff :)